# Retrieving Account Info from DBAccountInfo in Dropbox Datastore iOS API

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying to get a user's display name from the Dropbox Datastore API. The documentation for iOS says that DBAccountInfo is retrieved in the background, and to use an observer.

This is what I'm trying, but I'm getting nothing back (the block never fires):

```
NSLog(@"Here");
//-- Log: Here --

[[DBAccountManager sharedManager] addObserver:self block:^(DBAccount *acctInfo) {
  DBAccountInfo *info = acctInfo.info;      
  NSLog(@"Info: %@",info);
  //-- Log: <nothing> --
}];
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding an observer to the `DBAccountManager`, which will only fire when an account is linked or unlinked.

If you want to observe when the account info changes, you should add an observer to the `DBAccount`. Take a look at the [`DBAccount.addObserver:block:`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/ios#DBAccount.addObserver%3ablock%3a) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I get a crash (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) when I try this: `[account addObserver:self block:^(DBAccountInfo *info){ ... }];` Sorry, I'm relatively new to blocks and very new to the Datastore API. :)

Comment: Oh, and `account` is defined previously like this: `DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];`

Comment: The observer doesn't take any parameters, so you probably want `[account addObserver:self block:^() { ... }];`

Comment: Ah, that was it. I also had to create a weak reference to the `DBAccount` object before the block. I'll post the code below for posterity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code for anyone else that might be having trouble with this:

```
//Use weak reference because we are using `account` in a block
__weak DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];

[account addObserver:self block:^(){
  DBAccountInfo *info = account.info;
  NSLog(@"Info: %@",info);
}];
```